# Jinja2 conditions not working correctly while iterating

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I created a blog using Python, Google App Engine and Jinja2. I have an entity that holds who has liked a post, excluding the post author. I am iterating through all users that have liked a post and comparing it so that the user who created the post cannot like its own post. I also have an unlike button that should appear only when someone has liked a post. I am able to like and unlike the post; a user likes a post and the unlike button appears, the problem is that the like button doesn't go away it appears next to the unlike button, this causes a user to like the same post multiple times and shows as many unlike buttons as the user has clicked the like button. The variable `username` is the currently logged in user

```
{% for like in likes %} 
    {% if post.username != username and like.username != username %}
    <li>
        <form method="POST" id="likeForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="likePost" value="{{post.key().id()}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" form="likeForm">Like</button>
        </form>   
    </li>
    {% endif %}   
    {% if post.username != username and like.username == username %}
    <li>
        <form method="POST" id="unlikeForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="unlikePost" value="{{like.key().id()}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" form="unlikeForm">Unlike</button>
        </form>   
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the code's behaviour. The condition for displaying the `Like` button is:

```
{% if post.username != username and like.username != username %}
```

Meaning that a `Like` button will be displayed for every `like` in the `likes` list produced by users **other than** `username`, regardless of the fact that `username` liked the post or not. Probably not what you're after. You shouldn't display the `Like` while iterating on `likes`, you should only display it once, if after iterating through all `likes` you didn't find any produced by `username`.

As for the multiple `Unlike` buttons - I suspect you're not checking for an already existing `like` from `username` on a post when the `Like` button is pressed, thus allowing multiple such `like` instances in the `likes` list - each of them will cause an `Unlike` button to show up.

I'd just execute the logic in python (easier than in jinja2, probably faster as well):

```
if post.username != username:
    post.liked = False
    for like in likes:
        if like.username == username:
            post.liked = True
            break
```

and in jinja2:

```
{% if post.username != username %}
    {% if post.liked %}
        <li>
            <form method="POST" id="unlikeForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="unlikePost" value="{{like.key().id()}}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" form="unlikeForm">Unlike</button>
            </form>   
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>
            <form method="POST" id="likeForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="likePost" value="{{post.key().id()}}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" form="likeForm">Like</button>
            </form>   
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Note: code snippets not actually tested...